# sql query not executing on local host

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Below is a section of code contained in a file 'Column_details.php'. The goal is to display all attributes of a table when the user clicks on a table name. The table name is retrieved in $id. The issue is this query runs successfully on phpmyadmin. But does not run when Column_details.php is executed on localhost.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
$result = mysqli_query($conn,  "show fields from '$id'");
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row<=0){
    echo " No such columns";
}
else{
    echo "<table border='1'>";
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $col_name = $row['Field'];

                $click = "<a href='Column_details.php?mv= ".$col_name."'>" . "</a>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $col_name . "</td>";

                echo "<td>" . $click . "</td>";

          }
    echo "</table>";
}
$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post your connectionstring

Comment: @maSTArHiAn the connection string is  
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

Comment: and echoing $conn you get?

Comment: Also. Does it matter that your `<a>` tag has no content? And that your `<table>` is missing the closing `</tr>` tags?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I get ( ! ) Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\wamp64\www\Homework3\Column_details.php on line 18.

Comment: yup so that's your problem.. fix the connection first

Comment: @andrewsi NO it does not matter

Comment: @maSTArHiAn - indeed. Except with no content inside the `<a>` , he's generating an empty tag, which won't actually appear on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you sort out the connection you might want to fix your table

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            $col_name = $row['Field'];

            $click = "<a href='Column_details.php?mv= ".$col_name."'>" .$col_name. "</a>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $col_name . "</td>";

            echo "<td>" . $click . "</td>";

      }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the table. I have fixed the connection. But I still get an error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean .

Comment: can you do a basic select and not using show fields

Comment: I used the following query : SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$id' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbname' . But it returns 0 rows. So the "No such column" message is displayed.

Comment: suggest do a simple one. like 'select 1 [test]'